# Call every time typescript file whenever page reload or url change happened

Tags: angular, typescript, session, authentication, angular5

I need to implement a session in my angular 5 application. I want to write one ts file and basically, this ts file validates whether the user logged in or not. I want to call every time this ts file whenever page reloads or a URL change happens. How to implement?

Comment: It sounds like you want a router guard https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score -1):

Use `AuthGuard`.

Create a auth-guard.service.ts.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  canActivate() {
    console.log('i am checking to see if you are logged in');
    return true;
  }

  canActivateChild() {
    console.log('checking child route access');
    return true;
  }

}
```

After that in your routing file:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: DashboardUsersComponent,
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardUsersHomeComponent
          },
          {
            path: ':username',
            component: DashboardUserDetailsComponent,
            canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Below is few references link for you.

https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/canactivate-and-canactivatechild

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-route-guards-canactivate-and-canactivatechild-example

https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards

Comment: This answer solely depends on linked articles which is discouraged on SO. Please include the gist of the solution in your answer.

Comment: Edited my answer.